# Can I stop a link looking like a link?

Tags: html, css

I disabled my address link with the following:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false;" rel="nofollow">Overview</a>
```

This came from some suggestions in my last post.

However --- When I move the cursor over the link a hand appears to show it's a link even though it does nothing. Is there a way to stop the cursor changing to a hand?

Thanks,

Comment: If you don't want it to act like a link, and you don't want it to look like a link … why are you using a link in the first place?!

Comment: don't forget to mark your previous question correct.

Comment: pls, add a link to your other post, so the context is clear for other readers.

Comment: I forgot? I'll go back and check. That's strange I thought I marked it correct. Thanks.

Comment: My apologies, you did mark it correct :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your link isn't pointing anywhere, you could just remove the `href` from the tag, which will result in browsers rendering the link as just normal text. (no underline, no pointer cursor)

Answer (score 5):

Through CSS, `a { cursor: default; color: black; text-decoration:none; }`

This will remove the blue text, underline and the hand pointer that is normally default for browsers. Also, why are you using a tags, haha?

Comment: Hello Phil. I would like to use ActionLink but sometimes find it confusing. Can I even make it go to # with ActionLink ?

Comment: That I am not sure about, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a styling rule to affect this.  It is called the [cursor property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/cursor).  Just apply a rule like this to your link styles:

```
cursor: default;
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the cursor to `cursor:default;`, e.g.

```
<a href="#">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" style="cursor:default;">Link 2</a>
```

Link 2 will use the default arrow cursor.